# Calling stored procedures, passing NULL values, dealing with boolean values

Tags: .net, sql-server, stored-procedures

When calling a stored procedure I am concatenating values together, my question is how do you call a stored procedure but send a 'NULL' value in one of the params?

Lets say that AID = null, but if I pass that to my query I get an error?!

```
QueryConn.Execute("Search_Res " & Count & "," & AccessList("InvoiceLevel") & "," & AID)
```

Ok, so my next question is going to be how do I pass in a boolean variable?

Within my stored procedure the var @SearchChildren is either true or false, but how do I define this or should I go with an int and make things simple for myself and just use 0 or 1?

MS SQL Server 2005.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the parameter of the `Search_Res` stored procedure to be optional. @parameter = NULL.  When NULL value is passed the parameter is ignored.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.foo 
    @param INT = NULL 
AS 
BEGIN ...
```

Comment: Actually this was the basis for the answer that I used so I you get the 'tick.'

Thanks to everybody who answered.

Answer (score 8):

It looks like you're trying to execute an SP using an ad-hoc query rather than an ADO.Net DBCommand object.  Can't you just add "@SearchChildren  = null" to your string?

You can also set parameter values explicitly using the command object, it's relatively straightforward.

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Search_Res", QueryConn);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SearchChildren", DBNull.Value);
..
..
values = cmd.Execute();
```

Excuse the C#... my VB is rusty.

Answer (score 0):

In this case since you are passing the procedure call and arguments as literals you want `AID` to contain the string value "null", not a null value.

Alternatively, you should consider using bind parameters. It looks like your calling language is VB.NET, so I don't exactly know how to do that in that language, but there are lots of references.

I haven't used SQL Server, but I know that in Oracle it's basically illegal to pass boolean variables to stored procedures. Using an INT with a 0 or 1 value is recommended.