# SqlParameter "disappears" when assigned a value of null?

Tags: .net, sql-server, default-value, sqlparameter

I stumbled across the following issue recently:

Assigning a `null` to the Value property of an SqlParameter appears to cause the parameter to be omitted from the query rather than passing `NULL`. This results in a potentially misleading error message when the Stored Procedure has no default value for the parameter.

I have a database table with a column that accepts `NULL`.

```
USE [TheDatabase]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TheTable](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [TheValue] [varchar](50) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_TheTable] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

The table is populated using a Stored Procedure. Notice that the parameter targeting the column does not specify a default value.

```
USE [TheDatabase]
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE TheStoredProcedure
    @TheValue varchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO TheTable (TheValue) VALUES (@TheValue);
END
GO
```

Executing the Stored Procedure with a value and with a `NULL`both work fine:

```
USE [TheDatabase]
GO

EXEC [dbo].[TheStoredProcedure] @TheValue = 'A string for Algernon'
GO

EXEC [dbo].[TheStoredProcedure] @TheValue = NULL
GO
```

I run the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ExecuteStoredProcedure("A string for Algernon");

        ExecuteStoredProcedure(DBNull.Value);

        ExecuteStoredProcedure(null);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static void ExecuteStoredProcedure(object value)
    {
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection("Server=TheServer;Database=TheDatabase;Persist Security Info=False;Integrated Security=true;"))
        {
            connection.Open();
            using (var sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("TheStoredProcedure", connection) {CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure})
            {
                sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@TheValue", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50) {Value = value});

                try
                {
                    sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e);
                }
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now);
    }
}
```

The first two method calls run fine: The first adds the string to the table, the second adds a `NULL`, but calling `ExecuteStoredProcedure()` with a `null` results in the following error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Procedure or function 'TheStoredProcedure' expects parameter '@TheValue', which was not supplied.

From the documentation it appears that you should use `null` when you wish to use the default value of parameter in the Stored Procedure.

> This property can be set to null or Value. Use Value to send a NULL value as the value of the parameter. Use null or do not set Value to use the default value for the parameter.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.value?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Data_SqlClient_SqlParameter_Value

Since my parameter *does not have* a default value, some sort of error is to be expected. However, what we get seems misleading: an error indicating that the parameter was not received on the database side, as opposed to an error indicating an unexpected value (or rather: lack of value) on that parameter.

Or is this in fact expected behavior, that setting Value to `null` effectively excludes the parameter from being passed to the server on execution of the command?

**Update 20.01.2010**

The documentation has since been updated:

> This property can be set to `null` or `DBNull.Value`. Use **`DBNull.Value`** to send a NULL value as the value of the parameter. Use `null` or do not set Value to use the default value for the parameter.

It is perhaps not crystal clear, but it is at least unambiguous.

Key here is that the default value of the parameter as defined for the Stored Procedure comes into play if the `SqlParamer` object has a `null` for its Value property, and I can only assume that this is achieved "behind the scenes" by omitting it from the query execution.

I guess the lesson to learn here is to always define your Stored Procedures with default values on your optional parameters.

-S

Comment: See answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2113122/calling-stored-procedures-passing-null-values-dealing-with-boolean-values

Comment: As @RomaRuzich pointed out, your stored proc has a parameter that doesnt have a default value. Set `@TheValue varchar(50) = NULL` in your stored procedure to let it run with default value on db side.

Comment: Use DbNull.Value instead of passing a `null`

Comment: @shahkalpesh that's not a solution. That covers up the problem instead of solving it

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: I suppose OP is looking to pass null value to the proc which doesnt have default parameter. Passing DBNull.Value will achieve that. However, if you pass `null` (c#) it won't be treated as `DBNull.Value`. What do you think OP is looking for & how do you get to that?

Comment: @shahkalpesh why do you proposed the OP *change the stored procedure* then ?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: Because that is the way I think is the way it gets solved. Why do you think it "covers up the problem instead of solving it"?

Comment: @shahkalpesh you *don't* need to modify the stored procedure just to set the parameter to null. You use `DbNull.Value` instead. There's no "why do you think" about it. That's what the docs say as well, even if they seem to have a typo

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Assign null to a SqlParameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4555935/assign-null-to-a-sqlparameter)

Comment: @shahkalpesh in fact, there are several duplicate questions about this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best method of assigning NULL value to SqlParameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13981281/best-method-of-assigning-null-value-to-sqlparameter)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: OP already has an example of passing `DBNull.Value` which takes care. I am not sure how does one pass null (c#) value other than using `DBNull.Value`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Don't* set the value to `null` if you want to pass a NULL to the stored procedure

The docs are almost right. In the phrase :

> Use [Value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dbnull.value?view=netframework-4.7.2) to send a NULL value as the value of the parameter.

The link points to *[DbNull.Value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dbnull.value?view=netframework-4.7.2)*. That's a documentation error

Passing `null` instead of `DbNull.Value` means you want to use the stored procedure's default parameter. That part of the docs is correct :

> Use null or do not set Value to use the default value for the parameter.

**Update**

I just added [a Github issue](https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-api-docs/issues/1294) for this

Answer (score 1):

[SqlParameter.Value Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.value?view=netframework-4.7.2)

This property can be set to null or DBNull.Value. Use DBNull.Value to send a NULL value as the value of the parameter. **Use null or do not set Value to use the default value for the parameter**.

So for `value = null` you have to set a default value of your patameter.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE TheStoredProcedure
    @TheValue varchar(50) = NULL
```